# Why do I have the gnome-3-34-1804 snap package installed on Ubuntu 20.04 (after a clean install of 20.04)?

Tags: package-management, snap, 20.04

After a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 I entered `snap list` into the terminal just out of curiosity, to see what snap packages are installed. To my surprise I saw a package called `gnome-3-34-1804` there. My question is: why is it there? Ubuntu 20.04 uses Gnome 3.36. What is the gnome-3-34-1804 package there for?

I have only five snap packages installed, they are

```
core18
gnome-3-34-1804
gtk-common-themes
snap-store
snapd
```

I didn't install any snaps myself by hand, only installed a few apps using `apt` in the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

The gnome-3-34-1804 snap description is at `snap info gnome-3-34-1804`:

> description: |   This snap includes a GNOME 3.28 stack (the base
>   libraries and desktop   integration components) and shares it through
>   the content interface.

This means that your other gnome-based snaps connect to this snap in order to talk to Gnome.

You can test this by removing the snap. Suddenly your other gnome-based snaps won't work. Restore their function by re-installing the snap.

Comment: Thank you. It is new, since I did a clean install about 3 hours ago.

Comment: Probably due to snap-store